# Button not displayed in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to develop Windows Form Application using Visual Studio 2010.

I drag the buttons from toolbox on Form 1

[image]

After running the Aplication i am getting this output.

[image]

I dont see any button on the screen.

I tried Bring to front property , I checked the code also button is add in the form.

```cs
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(316, 62);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // button2
    // 
    this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(184, 118);
    this.button2.Name = "button2";
    this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
    this.button2.Text = "fdefdf";
    this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(439, 170);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Comment: Have you modified the .designer.cs file manually? Have you rebuilt the solution? The code you've provided doesn't look like it will be the problem. Also, have you resized the dialog on top? The one on top looks like it might be hiding the buttons underneath as you've placed them..

Comment: Thanks. FInally rebuilding the application helped with some more steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put this code in page_load?

```
button1.Visible = true;
button2.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this one might be simple in this particular case:

- The buttons are positioned outside of the form. The form is, lets say, 300x200 and the buttons are likely positioned at beyond those
  bounds.

I'm only responding to this because I wasn't sure if it was related to my issue or not, but it appears not to be.